# Function does not return the correct value unless I include a print statement

Tags: python

I am working through translating some Python code which makes use of a golden search algorithm to find a minimizer of a function. The issue is that the algorithm does not return the correct minimizer unless I uncomment both print functions, `print('in gold', obj(c,*args), yc, 'in gold')` and  `print('in gold', obj(d,*args), yd, 'in gold')`. This is exclusive to Python as I have translated this exact algorithm to Fortran and it works beautifully.

```
def optimizer(obj, a, b, args=(), tol=1e-6):
    """ golden section search optimizer
    Args:
        obj (callable): 1d function to optimize over
        a (double): minimum of starting bracket
        b (double): maximum of starting bracket
        args (tuple): additional arguments to the objective function
        tol (double,optional): tolerance
    Returns:
        (float): optimization result
    """
    
    inv_phi = (np.sqrt(5) - 1) / 2 # 1/phi                                                                                                                
    inv_phi_sq = (3 - np.sqrt(5)) / 2 # 1/phi^2     
        
    # a. distance
    dist = b - a
    if dist <= tol: 
        return (a+b)/2

    # b. number of iterations
    n = int(np.ceil(np.log(tol/dist)/np.log(inv_phi)))

    # c. potential new mid-points
    c = a + inv_phi_sq * dist
    d = a + inv_phi * dist

    yc = obj(c,*args)  
    #print('in gold', obj(c,*args), yc, 'in gold')   
    yd = obj(d,*args)
    #print('in gold', obj(d,*args), yd, 'in gold')   

    # d. loop
    for _ in range(n-1):
        if yc < yd:
            b = d
            d = c
            yd = yc
            dist = inv_phi*dist
            c = a + inv_phi_sq * dist
            yc = obj(c,*args)
        else:
            a = c
            c = d
            yc = yd
            dist = inv_phi*dist
            d = a + inv_phi * dist
            yd = obj(d,*args)

    # e. return
    if yc < yd:
        return (a+d)/2
    else:
        return (c+b)/2
```

Normally, I would just keep the print statements in there, but this is called throughout a larger set of code that I am trying to debug, making the output very costly to sort through. I am using VScode if that helps.

The objective function (`obj`) is `obj_last_period`, which is defined as:

```
def obj_last_period(d,x,par):
    """ objective function in last period """
    
    # implied consumption (rest)
    c = x-d

    return -utility.func(c, d, par)
```

where `utility.func(c, d, par)` is defined as:

```
def func(c, d, par):
    return func_nopar(c, d, par.d_ubar, par.alpha, par.rho)
```

where `func_nopar` is defined as:

```
def func_nopar(c, d, d_ubar, alpha, rho):
    dtot = d + d_ubar
    c_total = c**alpha*dtot**(1.0-alpha)
    return c_total**(1-rho)/(1-rho)
```

`par.d_ubar`, `par.alpha`, and `par.rho` are all global parameters, which have values of 0.01, 0.9, and 2, respectively.

As for sample output, for a value of x = 1.1595155892092217, d_low =1e-08, d_high = 1.1595155892092217, the object is called as

```
d_adj = golden_section_search.optimizer(obj_last_period,d_low,d_high,args=(x,par),tol=par.tol)
```

and returns a value of d_adj = 0.7166200494040755 (i.e., the minimizer) with no print statements (the associated value of the objective function is 2.1488103454406895 ), which is not the minimum (it actually happens to be the initial value of "c" on line 25 in the def for optimizer, which makes me think the program exits early for some reason?)

When I uncomment the print statements, the program returns d_adj = 0.10695155964918086 (value of objective is 1.1835203405861294), which is the correct minimum. The correct minimum corresponds to the results with my Fortran code so it has to be something specific to Python. I am not an experienced Python user and have really been learning as I go along translating everything into Fortran.

The source code is found at https://github.com/NumEconCopenhagen/ConsumptionSavingNotebooks/tree/master/02.%20DurableConsumptionModel
The specific part of the code that is causing me trouble is in the file "Last_Period.py". I figured sharing the link is likely easier, but if it is easier to just paste all the separate .py files I'm happy to do so!

Comment: Do you have an example of `obj` that we can try running this with? And sample of running it with expected output. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried running this with a simple quadratic function and it is returning the same results with and without the calls to print.

Comment: Running this again with your function I am still getting the same results with or without prints as expected. Can you reduce the methods to a single file (with no dependencies (other than numpy)) that still shows the problem? There is no reason for print statements to affect execution which suggests there is something else going on and removing everything else should help you narrow it down.